# Just Stuck in Install "Detecting file systems..."

Tags: system-installation, filesystem

I am just installing elementary OS Freya 0.3.1 and I'm stuck in progress of installation "detecting file system": There's no progress, just stuck in there? I appreciate any answer to it.